# CSV Level Loading Function Won't Set the Player Variable in the Game Class, but Why?

Tags: python

I've tried to set up a csv file loading system in my pygame project, to make it easier to make the levels and load them up in the game. I've followed the advice of some others, which led me to make these functions in a class I titles "game".

```
#CSV convert
def convert_csv_to_2d_list(csv_file: str):
    tile_map = []
    with open(csv_file, "r") as f:
        for map_row in csv.reader(f):
            tile_map.append(map_row)
    return tile_map

#CSV Based Level Loading, needs fixing (part of game class, henceforth the self. before all variables
        self.tile_map = convert_csv_to_2d_list(csv_file="Levels/Platforming/Level Map Potentially.csv")
        for row in range(len(self.tile_map)):
            for col in range(len(self.tile_map[row])):
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 1:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 1, self.tile_group)
                
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 2:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 2, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)
                
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 3:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 3, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)
                
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 4:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 4, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)
                
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 5:
                    self.player = sprites.Player(row * 32, col * 32, self.player_group, self.platform_group)
                
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 6:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 6, self.tile_group, self.platform_group)
        
                if self.tile_map[row][col] == 7:
                    sprites.Tile(row * 32, col * 32, 7, self.tile_group)
```

But the problem is that when I run my main script, I get a error like this:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'player'
> ```

I have no idea why this is, as I set the attribute in this for loop. [Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rQSTW0phqfH9xKlEFoJV3dpPeoWrm5Un/view?usp=sharing) to my entire script to keep this post short and sweet.

Comment: Is seems like Game.player is referenced before you create it. Does this if statement execute `self.tile_map[row][col] == 5`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the player is set when the for loop goes through the tile map, and the 'self.tile_map[row][col] == 5' is just parsing through the map. There shouldn't be any other instances except for when a new tile map is read, and this is just setting up the first level to try and get the system itself to function. The self.player is the only problem I have.

Comment: This is why a [mre]  is helpful. The line I referenced is where the `self.player` is created. In any case, it might be easier if you create your player sprite on initialisation and then move it to position when the tile map value is five, that way it will never be accessed before it exists.

Comment: Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. "*

Comment: The attribute `palyer`  is only created in case of `if self.tile_map[row][col] == 5`.

Comment: @importrandom The way I have my code set up would make it very cumbersome to make a minimal reproducible example, as it would require a lot of setup and script in the question itself. That's why I linked the project file I have, to make sure the question itself stays clean and simple. Though I do understand why it would be helpful. As for the attribute, it is made on initialization. If you looked at the file, you would see the '__init__' function is where this code lies. But next time I will make sure to try and provide the minimum code needed.

Comment: Do you have a ```self.player``` in your ```Game``` object constructor?

Comment: @JoboFernandez Please read the code in the question and the comments. Yes: `self.player = sprites.Player(...)`, however, it is only `if self.tile_map[row][col] == 5:`

Comment: If `len(self.tile_map)` and `len(self.tile_map[row])` both return a value greater than five, when `row` is five, then your `player` constructor will be called. As you're encountering an `AttributeError` that means that you're trying to refer to `Game.player` before you call `Game.convert_csv_to_2d_list()`. So reorganise your code to instantiate `player` in `Game.__init__()` and move the player position in `Game.convert_csv_to_2d_list()`.

Comment: @importrandom Ok, I'm genuinely sorry if I'm being dense here, but I am doing so I believe. The initialization code is where all this if `len(self.tile_map)` and all that is located, and then the update method uses other functions to check for the win or lose conditions I set for the player. It's there that the `self.player` is called to use the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` function. Please just tell me if you need me to post every script in the question, as I put a flipping link in the end with all my files, including scripts, images, and the sole csv file I'm using to test the system out.

Comment: It is also *cumbersome* and *dangerous* to download an run scripts of unknown provenance. I see that the `player` instantiation is in the __initi__ function, it wasn't clear when I was looking at your question. Anyway, what happens if you add `self.player = sprites.Player(5 * 32, 5 * 32, self.player_group, self.platform_group)`  after you create your groups?

Comment: I do make them after the groups. In the script, the loop that generates the level is the very last thing in the **init** method.

Comment: Hey there, been a little while. I tried instantiating a player before the loop and using the loop to set the player's position. But then I discovered the map wasn't drawn at all. So for now, until I can comprehend csv file shenanigans, I decided to use the method I've been using and just loop through lists in a seperate script. It may be more extensive, but for now it's the absolute best I can do. Especially since I haven't made any progress whatsoever since this thread. But thanks for all your help guys!